# парсер python+lxml

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Задался вопросом извлечь данные из подобного сайта http://mkrf.ru/ais-egrkn/

Необходимо произвести выборку данных в регионе "Карелия".
При помощи обычных *lxml* библиотеки и *xpath* запросов данные достать не получилось.

```
getReq = requests.get(URL) # Response 200
AllHtml = html.fromstring(getReq.text) # <Element html at 0x7f18453c8db8>
searchObj = AllHtml.xpath('..//*[@id="id_147784807571377968416"]/ymaps/ymaps/ymaps[1]/ymaps[1]') 
print(searchObj)
```

> Вывод: []

Подскажите новичку куда копать дальше:)

Comment: точки перед // не нужны.  А вообще Firefox+Firebug+FirePath вам в руки

Comment: @vitidev именно с помощью этих дополнений к Firefox и был получен этот путь. Проверил без точек. Результат такой же.
Сложность именно в доступе к тегам внутри карты Яндекса. Она как бы должна быть развёрнута мышкой, чтобы стать доступной. Как мне это видится